# Is there any way to display part of an image in a UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I only want to display part of an image in an UIImageView, not the whole image. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try cropping the original image:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:"my_image.png"]
CGRect *rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([myImage CGImage], rect);
UIImage *topLeftImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Or if you would like the user to be able to pan the image, you could add the image to a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: When I try anything with UIEdgeInsetsMake, the whole picture still appears. I'm trying to put the top-left 64x64 pixels of the larger image into a UIImageView. (then eventually any 64x64 part of the larger image)